# Android TextView quote text part + vertical line

Tags: android, textview, quote

I am looking for a solution to a problem with quoting part of a text in a TextView. 
There is a long text and some parts need to be quoted/highlighted.
I have made something in HTML (Html.fromHtml(String)) but without this red vertical line.
Do you have any idea how to add it ?
As far as I know, CSS styling is not possible in TextView.

[image]

Comment: this is too complex for a TextView. You can use a WebView for this.

Comment: why didt you use `<View/>` align left to textview?

Comment: "some parts need to be quoted/highlighted"  you mean portion of the text needed to be highlighted in Textview ?

Comment: @SohailZahid part of the text view should be highlighted, not whole part. I just read text from strings.xml and display it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes, I though so... But I was wondering is this possible in textView... Because TextView already supports Html.

Comment: TextView supports **some tags of HTML**, not entire HTML. And I don't know a tag that can do your task and is supported by TextView. So you either will have to implement your own TextView, or use WebView.

Comment: check below demo.

Answer (score 3):

> **Webview** with custom line view.
>
> **TextView** with custom line view.

**TextView**

[image]

**Webview**

[image]

**wrap_content**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <View
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#B1233A"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/webView"></WebView>

 <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="200dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:text="My textt from web \nand  in multiple \nLines"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/webView"></TextView>-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I understand this, but I have many strings and each has 1,2,3... parts of quoted text. So it must be added to text somehow, so the Android will know where to draw line.
In this solution, view is fixed and red vertical line is fixed.. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: you can inflate layout with with line and textview at runtime using for loop and them into linear layout ....then there could 100 string you dont write xml code for each one

Answer (score 1):

Do not use two view for it. You just create a xml background file as follows

bg_quote_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <size android:width="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

android:width="2dp" and android:left="2dp" are vertical line width. Finally you set bg_quote_text to background of TextView also do not forget to padding attribute.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_quote_text"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum "
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_artist" />
```

Its done.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FF0000FF" />
```

Comment: OP is trying to make portion of TextView text as highlighted and not full textview

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question but in case anybody else stumbles upon this, [QuoteSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/QuoteSpan) does exactly what you want:

```
val quoted = SpannableStringBuilder("here is some quoted text\n")
quoted.setSpan(QuoteSpan(myColor), 0, quoted.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
val entireString = SpannableStringBuilder()
entireString.append("before quote\n")
entireString.append(quoted)
entireString.append("after quote")
```